# All cluster resources were brought up, but: 1 nodes out of 1 are unhealthy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Unable to create a gke autopilot cluster using shared vpc .
The same shared vpc works fine with standard private cluster .
Repeated this multiple times with the same error. Followed google troubleshooting recommendations , no luck.

Invariably gke auto pilot nodes / instance group fail to create .
The nstall progress gets stuck at health checks at 83% .

Answer (score 0):

There is a [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#cant_create_cluster_due_to_health_check_failing) on this issue mentioning potential causes and possible solutions.

As per my understanding, and also considering the error message where it's failing after 83%. I suspect possibly automatically created firewall rules for ingress may have been either deleted or modified. If you check out [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/firewall-rules#ingress-fws) documentation, understand the purpose as this permits health checks of a NodePort Service or network endpoint group (NEG). Also, reconfigured DNS for *.gcr.io. would also result in the same time of issue. Therefore, I suggest carefully check each and every point.